# WordPress - generate whole HTML code in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I need to write plugin in WordPress to generate whole HTML Code not only for post content, but whole code.
I want to avoid take URL from MySQL and get code using "file_get_contents", because I need this option also for drafts, not only for published content.

Comment: Hi @Buc! Usually we want to see examples of what you have tried, and how you mean to use the code. Try to stay away from vague or incomplete answers :)

Comment: I need to generate this:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html class="html__responsive"><head><title>WordPress - generate whole HTML code in plugin - Stack Overflow</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8...`

I create basic plugin template, for published posts/pages I have worked 
`$test = file_get_contents('http://localhost/wordpress/?p=57');`
But this isn't the best way I don't know how use FrontController from WP to generate this without used **file_get_contents()** and based on WP functions.